# Combine MongoDB operations in a pipeline

Tags: mongodb

I am doing some String cleansing in an aggregation pipeline. One working stage is like:

```
{
  _id: "$_id",
  text: {
    $concat: ['$title', ' ', '$desc']
  }
}
```

I would like to add `$trim` and also clean `,;:.'` by replacing them with  .

Taking trim as an example I tried multiple ways like:

```
{
  _id: "$_id",
  text: {
    $trim: {input: $concat: ['$title', ' ', '$desc'] }
  }
}
```

but it is not well formatted and therefore not working.

Comment: In the question it is not clear what "not working" means.  I think you are missing the braces `{}` around the `$concat` operation.

Comment: you are right, I was missing braces. The error as I said is the format.

Comment: It would be more helpful if you can supplement with your sample dataset and expected output